# math negative numbers calculation apply to a jquery easing rotate

Tags: javascript, math, negative-number

I am using jquery easing plugin, I want to apply the easing "easeInOutBounce" to a div rotation, but not like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xtksjtcr/) (where, basing on 90, the rotation will be between 0 and 90):

```
num = 90;
$('div').animate({borderSpacing: num},{
    step: function(now){
        if(now >= num/2){xxx = num - now;}else{xxx = now;}
        console.log(xxx);
        $(this).css('transform','rotate('+ xxx +'deg)');
    },
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBounce'
},'linear');
```

I want to do the rotation not starting by 0, but converting partial of the value in negative numbers, so the animation is balanced to 0:
in this case basing on 90, I want the animation between -45 and 45.

I made a bad calculation and I can't achieve the result I want... please help with a proper math calculation, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try `now = now - num/2;` instead of your `if...` statement.

This corresponds to the mapping `now |--> now - 90/2` which has a range of [-45,45] when `now` has a domain of `[0,90]`.

Comment: I tried it but at the end of animation the "axis" does not return to center... I want to create a vibration effect.. Like a seismogram

Comment: can't figure out how to do it... maybe my question is not very clear, also for the multiple things involved... however, you answered to the question _as it is_ and I have to accept it :) thank for any help